# Is it possible to get access to additional inforamtion about transcations (such as recieptId) which using the Contract interface

Tags: nearprotocol

I'm currently using the call contract information (https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#call-contract) to make calls to my contract.

I'd like to get more information (e.g. receiptId, gas used) about the transactions which I just executed.

I see the example for checking gas used (https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-cookbook#calculate-gas) and in that example calls the account.functionCall interface directly.  Fromt he example it looks likee the receipt and gas information is part of that result returned .

The result of the my Contract interface calls seem to be only whatever data my contract function returns.  I've looked through the code a bit and I suspect this interface does call functionCall as well, but on return I think pulls out the data returned and discards the rest in the return.

Is there a way to get additional information such as what was the transaction hash, receipt  receiptId and gas information when using Contract interface (i.e.contract.method({args}) or do I need to use the functionCall interface directly to get that detail?

Thanks
Marvin

Comment: I don't think you can. You have to use `functionCall`. Please have a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/71004135/1471485

Answer (score 0):

**On python:**

`pip install py-near`

```py
from pynear.providers import JsonProvider
import asyncio


async def main():
    provider = JsonProvider()
    await provider.startup()
    data = await provider.get_tx("7iCMW3yo5GEksU8UyeLN66Vai56Mw26McbFXh8KWLn3", "mydev.near")
    print(data['transaction_outcome']['outcome']['receipt_ids'])

asyncio.run(main())
```